# Link should only be visible to the superuser and the group

Tags: python, django

I have the below url for in the _base.py which will render a link in the left side when the user hovers a section called Uploads,

```
{'label': 'Upload User Data', 'url': '/admin/user/bulk_user_update/', 'permissions': 'bulkupdate.access_user'},
```

I want this url only to visible to the superuser and the current permission `bulkupdate.access_user`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this :

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
  <a href="#"> link only superusers can view </a>
{% else %}
   <a href="#"> superuser can't view this link (anyone other than super user can view this link) </a>
{% endif %}
```

@**Update**

So in the SUIT_CONFIG you can add the user is a super user or not as shown below

```
{'label': 'Upload User Data', 'url': '/admin/user/bulk_user_update/', 'permissions': ('bulkupdate.access_user', 'user.superuser')},
```

Now we need to block the html if the user directly enter the url on the browser so for that you can use the template if else condition as shown by @Sreevardhan, a small update is there. See below

```
{% block content %}



{% if not request.user.is_superuser %}
  <div>Please raise a ticket for access</div>
{% else %}
   <div>Please upload the file ....</div>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response , so i need to add this in the template isn't. how should i return back him , the link itself should not be visible

Comment: how can i do a return in the html file ,

Comment: I have updated the code, anything inside template tags will be visible to superuser only

Comment: No may be you have understood wrongly, left side you have section called uploads, when hovering on it i will get a bunch of links which are given through _base.py. as in the question, i dont want to show that url itself. Inside uploads section you will Upload team data, upload user data, upload config data .... like wise

Comment: i want to hide Upload user data when hovering on Uploads, so where should i check that user is super user, can i pass something like this 
{'label': 'Upload User Data', 'url': '/admin/user/bulk_user_update/', 'permissions': 'bulkupdate.access_user', 'user': 'super_user'},

Comment: No, I cannot understand, what do you want exactly? could you care to elaborate?

Comment: once you login to the admin page the left side you will have sections isn't, assume there is a section called uploads, so when the user hover on the uploads it will show a box where you have three links Upload team data, Upload user data, Upload config data. So if the user is not a super_user then he wont be able to see Upload user data

Comment: Thanks for the response but i dont have the html page i pass this config in the SUIT_CONFIG in that config how can i check for the permission

Comment: @ Sreevardhan i got the solution thanks for the help, i have added to the solution also kindly check so it will be helpful for others